# Why do we need a rabies vaccine after exposure?

Tags: treatment, vaccination, rabies

So I understand the need for rabies vaccination "before" exposure since the vaccine basically prepares the immune system, so that in the future should the same intruder enter the body again, the immune system already knows how to handle it.

What I dont understand however is the need of an immediate rabies vaccine for a person after he/she has been exposed to rabies virus (bitten, scratched by a rabid dog) , assuming he/she has not been vaccinated before.

The rabies virus is already in the saliva of the rabid animal right? and the immune system should already start making the necessary antibodies to counter it right? What's the purpose of injecting a weaker version of the virus if the immune system is going to create the antibodies anyway?

Is the immune system more effective, efficient and quick in creating a solution if it is introduced to a much weaker version of the virus? And after figuring out a "fix", it applies this to the original, strong version of the virus?

Or is the immune system not very responsive to the original virus and it must be "triggered" first to create the necessary "fix" by introducing a weaker version with which it is more responsive?

In any case, I'm quite lost on this.

Comment: The vaccine help the immune system to develop a quicker response to the threat. If not you can die before your immune system figured out how to fight the virus

Comment: @holyknight but after the bite, you already have the live virus in your body. What is the advantage of adding more virus (dead or alive) through vaccine? Why would the virus from the vaccine help immune system to develop a quicker response as compared to the virus from the bite?

Answer (score 1):

It is because rabies [take time to kill you](https://www.ccohs.ca/oshanswers/diseases/rabies.html#wb-auto-4) and vaccine that you [are given is 'dead' virus](https://www.cdc.gov/vaccines/hcp/vis/vis-statements/rabies.html) so it makes it easy to develop antibodies against and when you have antibodies you can fight actual virus

Comment: But you already have a live virus inside your body because of the dog bit. That should make it easy for your immune system to create antibodies. What advantage does it give to also add dead virus? Shouldn't immunoglobulin be enough as treatment?

Comment: @user93353 the real virus works in such a way your immune system can't handle. Here's a good YouTube on it https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4u5I8GYB79Y&ab_channel=Kurzgesagt%E2%80%93InaNutshell

Comment: I know that the real virus is more dangerous. However, it's already inside the body of someone who has been infected. So what's the point of adding an inactivated virus into the picture.

Comment: Cause your body can handle the inactivated virus and make antibodies before you die from the real thing? :) I must be missing something.

Comment: But if the real thing is already inside you, then why is the body not making antibodies already? Does the body make antibody faster with inactivated than with real virus? Else this makes no sense

Comment: I did watch the video. What it says is - quoting - "vaccine prepares your immune system". It doesn't say how. What does the vaccine do different from the virus which triggers the immune system which virus didn't.

Comment: I've posed this question many years ago, and from my understanding since then, is that it all comes down to the timing of things happening.

You see, rabies takes time (hours) to fully latch on and affect the brain, but if you get vaccinated, the body has a chance to create antibodies so that it can fight the real virus on its way to the brain and destroy them before they even arrive. 

The body is really fast on this process, which is why the common advice given to people who just got bit is to get the vaccine ASAP and not delay it.

Comment: @user93353 The first thing the vaccine gives the body is the ability to "identify and recognize" the rabies virus signature. Normally, rabies passes through the immune system undetected, but with the vaccine, the immune system learns to identify the bad guys. 

The second thing that the vaccine teaches the body is that rabies is really, really dangerous, and must be taken it out asap, I don't know the technical details as to how the vacc. does this, I just know it works. Which is why the body-as a response to the vacc-swiftly creates anti-bodies which destroys both the real and vac. virus

Comment: @Johnsy - my question is about the technical reasons. Why can body recognize the virus in the vaccine but not the virus itself from the dog bite? And how do you know it works - immunoglobin is also given with the vaccine. So may be it's the immunoglobin which works.

Comment: @user93353 Like I said, I don't really understand the technical aspects of it, I've read the papers and it was super academic with chemical/mRna illustrations and stuff. I just know that scientists have worked out a way for the body to be able to detect the virus, and teach it to attack it. Because that's really the main problem, rabies virus goes undetected in the body. But if you take a dead rabies virus and tweak some features in it, then somehow it teaches the body for detection, and easily kills the real virus. Science man. You should read the published papers if you want to delve more.

Comment: @user93353 As for the second question, how do we know it works? Well, the people don't die from rabies.

Comment: @Johnsy  - that would be good proof if **only** the rabies vaccine was given after a dog bite. But both immunoglobin & the vaccine are given. So it could also be true that people didn't die because of the immunoglobin was given & the rabies vaccine didn't do anything much to help.

Comment: @Johnsy - do you have a link to any published paper which explains how the vaccine helps the body detect the virus which it otherwise wouldn't have detected? And what features were tweaked into the inactivated virus so it achieves this?